# ListBox Deceleration

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.5

In WPF 4.0, I used a property on the ScrollViewer to change the deceleration like this:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.PanningDeceleration="0.001" />
```

It seems in WPF 4.5, I no longer have access to ScrollViewer.  How do I change the panning deceleration in WPF 4.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried it in a WPF Application with .Net 4.5. The attached property is there. You even got Intellisense after you typed `Scrollviewer.`
What exactly do you mean with no access?

Comment: I just had some Intellisense issues.